# When are queries executed on DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to understand the performance impact of having one DbContext class vs multiple when using EF6 framework.

For example, if we have a simple DbContext such as this:

```
public class MainDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public void AddCar(Car car)
    {
        Cars.Add(car);
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now let us say I have a service that uses the said DbContext in the following way:

```
public class CarService
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; private set; }
    public CarService()
    {
        var dbContext = new MainDbContext();
        Cars = dbContext.Cars.ToList();
    }
}
```

At what point in time did the DbContext go to the database and retrieved all cars that are stored in the database? Was it when I called `var dbContext = new MainDbContext();` or was it when I called `Cars = dbContext.Cars.ToList();`?

If former, if I had a DbContext that contains 100 tables, will all 100 tables be queried when the DbContext is created?

Comment: `At what point in time did the DbContext go to the database and retrieved all cars that are stored in the database?` In that code? Never. It will not work, the `Cars` property on the DBContext should be of type `DbSet<Car>`

Comment: Even if it's a `DbSet<T>`, it'll only fetch data from the database when you explicitly tell it to by calling something like `ToList()`. `Cars` by itself doesn't do anything - it's a container for entities but it's not holding all the data unless you make it so. If you use `IQueryable` with Linq, data will only be pulled when you evaluate the enumerator or when you execute a SQL statement against the underlying connection through the context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The query happens once you enumerate a table. Even in your second example, it still does not connect to the database.

It will connect when you enumerate, for example:

```
dbContext.Cars.ToList();
```

Or

```
foreach (Car c in dbContext.Cars)
```

Or bind the table to a UI control.

However when you make a where, order by, then by, join etc.. e.g.

```
var result = dbContext.Cars.Where(c => c.Id == 35).OrderBy(c => c.Name);
```

You will *not* connect to the database. You are only preparing the logical sequence of operations to translate into an SQL query.

---

**AFTER THE QUESTION UPDATE**

Now, your second example, with the ToList(), enumerate the results and connects to the database to get the data.